# Alert dialog not working correctly - android

Tags: java, android, button, alert

I am using an alert dialog to ask the user for confirmation of an item addition to an array.  I am printing the array size before and after the alert dialog and it seems that both printings are done before the alert dialog shows up.

```
Log.d("before", ""+wayPoints.length);
AlertDialog.Builder ab = new AlertDialog.Builder(getContext());
ab .setTitle("Add entry");
ab .setMessage("Are you sure you want to add this entry?");
ab  .setPositiveButton(android.R.string.yes, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() 
{
      public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) 
    {wayPoints = ArrayHandler.addAtIndex(wayPoints, node, 1);}
});
ab .setNegativeButton(android.R.string.no, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) { 
                        // do nothing
                    }
                 });
ab.setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_alert);
ab.show();
Log.d("after", ""+wayPoints.length);
```

The ArrayHandler.addAtIndex method handles the addition of a new item to the provided array. 
The problem is it is printing both logging lines before the alert dialog shows up. I need the alert dialog to be done before the printing of the second log.

Comment: User this code " AlertDialog ad = alertDialog.create();
    ad.show(); "  instead of " ad.show(); "

Comment: The same thing happens the other Log is printed before the alert dialog is shown @SurenderKumar

Comment: You mean to say that both logs "before" and "after" are showing up before dialog is shown.

Comment: yes. I don't the other log to be shown unless the user gets the dialog and press wither of its buttons if possible. @SurenderKumar

Comment: put your after log inside positive button click and check what output is coming.

Comment: the problem is that I don't anything after the alert dialog to be executed unless the dialog is already shown and the user pressed a button not only the logging part.

Comment: Its not possible to show the logs after the dialog shown because you are printing logs outside the dialog.

Comment: In other words, look at my answer because I tried explaining this in great detail and got a -1 vote for it :(

Answer (score 1):

This is **correct behavior**. The `show` method does not wait or block until the dialog is dismissed. Code execution continues after the `show` method immediately after the dialog is shown. (Actually, the dialog isn't even displayed yet - that happens after you yield control).

You already have `setPositiveButton` and `setNegativeButton` handlers, just put the code you want to execute in those handlers when user presses a button.

If you want certain code to run when the dialog is closed **regardless of which button is tapped**, use `setOnDismissListener` and **put your code there**.

Comment: I want the second log to be printed after the dialog is closed wether the user pressed OK or cancel

Comment: I don't the execution of the code to continue unless the user finish pressing On the buttons in the alert dialog

Comment: In that case, put the code you want to execute **in the handler**. You can argue with me if you want, but that wont change the way the framework functions.

Comment: I'm not sure what do you mean. 
But the function I want is the user to be asked if he wants to add a point if he presses yes it adds it and if no it doesn't add it then it continues with whatever after the dialog part. 

i'm not sure if the dialog can be done for this or not but I need this functionality :) 

I hope you understand what I need

Comment: Of course I understand. In your click listener for positive answer, add the point. In your click listener for the negative answer, don't add the point. "Continues with whatever" can be a function you call from both click listeners, or one. It's up to you.

Comment: See my edit about using `setOnDismissListener`. See? You need to add a listener to run code AFTER the dialog has closed.

Comment: is there a better option than an alert dialog that doesn't need an on dismiss listener ?

Comment: Why can't you use click listeners and dismiss listeners? They do exactly want you want

Comment: okay how to use it :) 

is it a method of the AlertDialog class ?

Comment: Yes it is very straightforward to use. If you need further help a simple google search will give you nice examples. For now it would be best to just accept my answer to bit confuse others who see -1 and think it is somehow not correct

Comment: Thanks man it is working perfectly. 
I wish I can vote up but the problem is I don't have 15 reputation, 

Thanks anyway :)

Answer (score -1):

Use:

```
AlertDialog alert1 =  ab.create();
alert.show();
```

Instead of:

```
ab.show();
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(               context);  
            // set title        
    alertDialogBuilder.setTitle("Your Title"); 
            // set dialog message   
        alertDialogBuilder              .setMessage("Click yes to exit!")               .setCancelable(false)               .setPositiveButton("Yes",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {    
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int id) {        
                // if this button is clicked, close             
            // current activity             
            MainActivity.this.finish();                     }           
     })                 .setNegativeButton("No",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() { 
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int id) {        
                // if this button is clicked, just close            
            // the dialog box and do nothing            
            dialog.cancel();        
            }       

.setPositiveButton(android.R.string.yes, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
 public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
wayPoints = ArrayHandler.addAtIndex(wayPoints, node, 1);

Log.d("after", ""+wayPoints.length);
} });   
    });         
            // create alert dialog      
            AlertDialog alertDialog = alertDialogBuilder.create();  
                    // show it  
                alertDialog.show();
```

Comment: @moe add log line code inside onclick listener as shown in the answer

Comment: Thats what I told him in great detail and got a -1 vote for taking the time to give him a detailed answer and explanation

Comment: @greg how can we tackle this negative voting if the answer is correct

Comment: I don't know, seems some angry downvoter took over this topic